# Paypal vault for recurring payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, pci-compliance, paypal-vault

I'm going to offer my customers a selection of subscriptions to digital content.  I want the customer to be able to add or delete subscriptions later, with as little hassle as possible.

It seems that if I use Paypal vault, I can collect the card information on the same subscriptions screen without multiple redirects and later change the monthly total without another checkout process or even customer sending approval to Paypal!

Does Paypal allow this?  It seems too easy and also too permissive.  Also, do I need to worry about PCI compliance?

Does anyone know a better way to do this (with or without Paypal)?  I don't know how to use paypal recurring payments without a lengthy checkout if they ever change their subscriptions.  Google wallet does not have subscription cancellation in their API! Several other alternatives only allow preset subscription amounts.

Comment: I just figured out how to do subscriptions with Braintree.  It was very easy and flexible.  I would still like to hear anyone's ideas because it might be helpful for future projects or for others.

Comment: I'm also interested in this solution or answer.

Answer (score 0):

The CSC/CVV is missing from the examples here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/ which makes me think you cannot use the card at will. The customer is probably going to be asked for authorisation.

Normally your online payment provider needs to support recurring payments (installments, subscriptions). PayPal does, there's a specific API:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/installment_buttons/

For the customer it's one-off, then the card is billed, say, monthly.